How to suppress address sanitizer leak check for specific leak
I'm trying to use asan for a specific compiler version for a program build on Debian bookworm amd64.
The trouble is that the program calls into OpenSSL which in turn uses strerror_l before even encountering any error. But for that purpose a buffer is malloc'ed and never free'd. Hence asan reports a leak:
=================================================================
==3284474==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 17 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7f2515706d68 in __interceptor_malloc /home/tjahns/Documents/work/dkrz/build/spack/var/spack/stage/gcc-9.1.0-d3fldzlztdy4oau2lmzej6g5f23wkioy/spack-src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cc:144
    #1 0x7f251089d427  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x7e427)
    #2 0x7f2510870bd5 in __asprintf (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x51bd5)
    #3 0x7f25108bd9f0 in strerror_l (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x9e9f0)
    #4 0x7f250f134895 in ERR_load_ERR_strings (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.2+0x134895)
    #5 0x7f250f135b08 in ERR_load_crypto_strings (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.2+0x135b08)
    #6 0x7f250f641ab8 in SSL_load_error_strings (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.2+0x41ab8)
[...unrelated function calls from the program left out]
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 17 byte(s) leaked in 1 allocation(s).

Since I don't know how to make strerror_l release that buffer, I was wandering if there is a way to suppress this specific leak as there is for valgrind.
I can of course forego all leak checking, but I'd rather have it modulo the one leak above I can't do much about.
Any suggestions to prevent disabling of leak checks completely appreciated. Probably doesn't matter, but the program in question is written in C.

Turns out, the suppression mechanism for leak sanitizer is different from asan:
printf "%s\n" 'leak:strerror_l' >"suppFile"
export LSAN_OPTIONS="exitcode=0:fast_unwind_on_malloc=0:suppressions=suppFile:print_suppressions=0"

gives what I wanted.
